# What's the best way to get a value of a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, substring

I have this huge string that's a key value of an object of mine (I didn't make this, it was generated by a bot).

I'm trying to grab the text out on the front end and display it. So in the case of: "text : hi" I'd want to grab 'hi' out and display it. I know I can search for the text using substrings, but the only thing I know if that 'text' will be there, but I want the data after it and I don't know what that data will be every time.

```
"{"event": "user", "timestamp": 1583019471.5611057, "text": "Alex", "parse_data": {"intent": {"name": "utter_interview", "confidence": 0.6946980357170105}, "entities": [], "intent_ranking": [{"name": "utter_interview", "confidence": 0.6946980357170105}, {"name": "utter_greet", "confidence": 0.18765409290790558}, {"name": "utter_closeout", "confidence": 0.11764788627624512}], "text": "Alex"}, "input_channel": "rest", "message_id": "0375d021d0fd4a8eb2ff8f519c72d8d6", "metadata": {}}"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That looks like JSON, have you tried... *parsing* it?

Comment: Yes the data has been fetched and parsed and i'm console logging it as JSON, this is one of the key value pairs. Sorry If that's not what you're asking?

Comment: But that value is *also* JSON. So you can parse *that* into JavaScript objects.

Comment: Since you say it is a string, then this is JSON, and *still needs parsing*. Call `JSON.parse` on it, and you'll get an object.

Comment: Ah okay yes. I’ll give that a shot :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can go for

```
const data = JSON.parse(string);
const text = data.text
```

If the string that you pasted is the value in the parsed JSON, you need to further parse it which is the above step.

However, if you don't want to parse it, you can use regex and match the text key.

Comment: Glad that I could help!